# Login using javascript in context of session id

Tags: javascript, session

i have one website that generates a session id and opens another website in the context of this session id.i want one button to open the first site and than automaticaly login on the second site.

site 1:http://thisisanexample/example leads to http://thisisanotherexample/another

this opens the the first site and the second site is opened afterwards:
    
    var myWindow;

```
function openWin() {
myWindow = window.open("http://thisisanexample/example");
}
</script>
```

after here i'm stuck. How could i submit the following Post request to site 2

```
<form action="http://thisisanotherexample/another/" method="POST" name="logonForm">
    <input type="text" name="user" value="placeholder">
    <input type="hidden" name="passwordnew1" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="passwordnew2" value="">
    <input type="password" name="password" value="placeholder">
    <input type="hidden" name="welcomescreen" value="1">
    <input type="submit" value="Anmelden" name="cmd_login">
```

I hope you get what i mean :-)

Comment: The feature you are trying to implement is called "Single Sign In".  This article may help you: https://auth0.com/learn/how-to-implement-single-sign-on/

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com/otherSite?name=ferret";
```

to navigate to the second site while passing the username and possibly the password via a query string parameter. The second site will have some kind of method to accept these arguments and automatically log the user in. It's highly recommended that you encrypt the query string data somehow.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13